# Comparing linear mixed-effect models with unequal sample sizes?

Tags: r, mixed-model, anova

I performed a mixed-effect linear regression on two models in R:

`i <- lme(ICC ~ CONDITION + LAB + COG, random=class/student, data=data1, na.action=na.omit)`

`j <- lme(ICC ~ CONDITION + LAB + COG, random=class/student, data=data2, na.action=na.omit)`

Data1 has 26 subjects, Data2 has 59 subjects, so when I try to use an ANOVA such as this:
`anova(i, j, refit = FALSE)`

I get the following error:

```
all fitted objects must use the same number of observations
```

I'm not sure how I can overcome this issue, how can I compare the two models?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, `anova` performs a likelihood ratio test for models that are nested - that is, where 1 model's parameters are a subset of the other's. Here the parameters are the same. Also, it is for comparing models that are fitted on the *same* dataset.

Don't fit two models. Fit one model on the whole dataset and include whatever variable you are using the split the data as a covariate along with an interaction with that variable and your main exposure. For example, if `data1` was males only and `data2` was females only, then include the `sex` variable in the model for the whole dataset.

```
lme(ICC ~ CONDITION*sex + LAB + COG, random=class/student, data=data_all, na.action=na.omit)
```

Comment: What difference does that make though? I'll still have something that looks something like this: `i <- lme(ICC ~ CONDITION + LAB + COG, random=class/student, data=data1, na.action=na.omit, subset=sex=="male")`...  this still does not generate a comparison between male and female

Comment: The difference is that you have *much* more statistical power due to the larger sample size. The example in your comment still is a subset (looks like there might be a typo too)

Comment: Ive edited the question to show how you might do it.